# Im confused when it comes to increasing/decreaseing a value by a ratio

Tags: ratio

Im currently doing GCSE maths and the current topic is ratios. Im comfortable sharing a value between ratios but im confused by questions like

```
Increase £30 in the ratio of 5:2
```

My materials arent very clear and its frustrating me, could someone please explain the method for calculating this type of answer?

Comment: speaking as someone who has taken GCSE maths (A* grade) this is probably saying "multiply by 5/2", but i'd need to see the full question to be sure, if you'd care to share in a separate discussion i'd be happy to explain it

Comment: That is the full question :) and yes you are correct, i had a brain fart a moment ago and the method is now obvious looking at the material. However I do struggle understanding the reasons behind methods. That causes me to over think things rather than just carry out the method.

Comment: another example is `Decrease 75cm in the ratio 2:3` so 75 x 2/3 = 50

Comment: Hi iNoob. Remember to upvote (and in some cases accept) answers that you found helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what they are thinking is:

(new number of pounds):(old number of pounds)::5:2

Or in words: the ratio of the result to the starting value should be the same as 5 to 2.

So if our result is X, we have $$\frac X{30} = \frac52$$

Multiply both sides by 30 to find X.

Comment: I did `30 / 2 = 15 x 5 = 75`

Comment: @iNoob That looks right to me!